# Loading background images from css file in meteor

Tags: meteor

I am building a meteor application for the first time and have run into some issues. In particular, I'm trying to get a picture viewer to work but the right and left arrows in the navigation buttons seem to be missing. When I attempt to load the images that are supposed to be in the button using google's developer tools, it's being displayed as an empty image. Thus, it's probably a case of me not putting the image file in the appropriate directory and as a result meteor is not able to load it in the css file. I'm not sure if this is the case or it's something else. It's probably not any syntax errors as I'm able to see the arrows in the button when I run the plugin outside of meteor.

Here's the line in my css file:

```
background: transparent url('themes.gif') no-repeat left top;  margin-top: -45px;
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

So I managed to get it to work. I created a resources directory in the public folder and changed the url in the css file to `url("/resources/button")`, which seemed to do the trick.

Answer (score 14):

You can leave your CSS as it is and put the themes.gif file in the `/public` directory of your Meteor app -- then it should be accessible.

Per the [docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#structuringyourapp):

> Lastly, the Meteor server will serve any files under the public directory, just like in a Rails or Django project. This is the place for images, favicon.ico, robots.txt, and anything else.

Comment: I've tried this but it doesn't seem to work. Could it be because I'm developing on windows?

Comment: Hmm. It might be. can you type `http://localhost:3000/themes.gif` to see your image? If not, there's a problem. Have you considered VirtualBox on Windows? That's what I do -- Meteor changes too rapidly to try to use the windows shim in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

You have to prefix a `/` in front of your file name.

Answer (score 2):

[my web site architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8OoyY.png)

```
body{   
  background-image: url('image/back1.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Comment: Not sure why this was negative voted. Upvoting because it helped with my case. Thanks.

Comment: Worked for me. Don't get it though, why I need to place them both under 'client' and 'public' folder

Answer (score 2):

Files need put to /public directory and remove "/public" in path from css.

For example:
If Image in path - `/public/img/logo.png`

Then use below CSS :

```
background-image('img/logo.png');
```

Comment: Thank you. This answer solved the problem for me. Chiefly, not including "public" in the URL.